# como mostrar resultados en laravel luego del consulta sin un numero de pagina

Tags: laravel

tengo una preguna según mi siguiente consulta:

```
 $ventas = Ventas::orderBy('nro_venta', 'DESC')

 ->with(['clientes' => function($query) use ($cliente)
  {
        if($cliente){ 
        $query->where('cliente', 'like', "$cuit_cliente");
        }
  }])
  ->fecha($fecha_inicial,$fecha_final)
  ->Paginate(6);
```

Los resultadosde la busqueda los paso a mi vista

```
   @foreach($ventas as $venta)
       
        <td>{{ $venta->fecha }}</td>
   
   @endforeach

      {{ $ventas->links() }}
```

Mi pregunta es como hago para que las filas se construyan de acuerdo a los datos obtenidos en la búsqueda, es decir; si tiene cien registros muestre 100 filas en la view y no grupos de 6? entiendo que el paginate, le indica que pagine en grupos de 6 pero como haría yo para que muestre sin paginar todos los resultados según la cantidad de filas que consiga?, espero que alguien pueda ayudarme porque he buscado pero no consigo como hacerlo, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Comment: Pues entonces no hagas paginación y solo usa el método `get`

Comment: gracias es correcto, saludos